# Why is the [hidden] attribute and 'display: none style' not working on my <div> tag containing an SVG tag in Angular html Component?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, svg

I'm trying to hide my svg tag using the parent div tag, but it doesn't seem to be hiding either the **read more** div or the **svg tag** within it, using either the [hidden]--attribute, or bootstrap 'd-none' or css display:none;

```
<div  class="d-flex" [hidden]="true">
<div class="read-more mr-2">read more</div>
        <svg class="icon icon-read_more align-self-center bg-light">
          <use xlink:href="assets/symbol-defs.svg#icon-read_more"></use>
        </svg>
</div>
```

or

```
  <div  class="d-flex d-none">
    <div class="read-more mr-2">read more</div>
            <svg class="icon icon-read_more align-self-center bg-light">
              <use xlink:href="assets/symbol-defs.svg#icon-read_more"></use>
            </svg>
    </div>
```

Comment: What does your browser say when you inspect the div element? Is the css applied?

Comment: @Johannes Stadler yes it's applied

Comment: @Johannes Stadlerd @Marc      -      `flex {
    display: -ms-flexbox!important; rulled out
    display: flex!important; not ruled out
}
[hidden] {
    display: none!important; ruled out
}`

Comment: Then that's the problem, something applies "display: flex!important;" and that wins (that's why it's not ruled out) over the [hidden] {display: none!important;}. So you have to check where this is coming from and why you should avoid !important at all costs.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Proper way should be:

```
<div class="d-flex" hidden>
   <!-- inner div content -->
</div>
```

Another option would be to use the `visibility` attribute:

`visibility: visible;` versus `visibility: hidden;`

Comment: Another option would be to use the ```visibility``` attribute:

```visibility: visible;``` versus ```visibility: hidden;```

Comment: visibility: hidden; works Thanks. But why doesn't the hidden attribute and display:none work?

Comment: I ran into this same situation. Yes, visibility:hidden works, but why doesn't display:none work? I want to hide the element and also not leave empty space for it.

Comment: Best place to understand the fine points imo is here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/hidden. You may want to use the live playground there to quickly experiment with the different attribute options. hope it helps